# C++ Using MACRO without INCLUDE statement

Tags: c++

In [DirectX Graphics Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples) MiniEngine sample, there is an "inline" source file [Functions.inl](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/MiniEngine/Core/Math/Functions.inl) that uses a macro `INLINE` that is defined in a header in same folder, [Common.h](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/MiniEngine/Core/Math/Common.h) .

What mechanism/declaration permits Functions.inl to use `INLINE` without an `#include "Common.h"` statement?

My specific issue is that I have created a VS2019 UWP C++ project, and I am importing a subset of this source and cannot compile the copy of Functions.inl without modifying and adding an `#include` statement.

Comment: Some people use `*.inl` extension as an implementation detail source file that is `#include` by another header file.  In this case `VectorMath.h` does a `#include "Math/Functions.inl"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Math/Functions.inl" is not a source file. It is not compiled individually. It appears to be included, just like a header is. Let's take a look at how it is used:

```
// Core/VectorMath.h
#pragma once

#include "Math/Scalar.h"
...
#include "Math/Functions.inl"
```

Unlike a header, it is not included into the top of the file, but the bottom. So, I guess it could be called a footer. As you may notice, there are headers included before it. Let's take a look inside one:

```
// Math/Scalar.h

#pragma once

#include "Common.h"
...
```

Ah. So, "Common.h" **is** included before "Math/Functions.inl". That is why "Math/Functions.inl" can use `INLINE` when included into "Core/VectorMath.h".

---

Essentially, the file depends on a macro without including it directly and thereby it has an invisible dependency to have that header included before it.

This a bad practice in case of header files which are intended to be included by the user of the library. But this file is presumably intended to *not* be included except through "Core/VectorMath.h", so the the invisible dependency can even be seen as advantageous. Nevertheless, many IDEs / static code analysers will fail to analyse the file correctly, so I would personally still avoid this practice.

Comment: In this case, I don't think it's as bad of practice (although not what I'd like), because I don't think the `*.inl` file is supposed to be included by the client directly.  Rather (I think) it is an implementation detail, so its context is controlled by the developer of this package.  Unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Eljay I added more explanation to my opinion.

Comment: @Eljay In addition to what I wrote in the answer, the developer of the package still has the burden of having to know that "Core/VectorMath.h" has to include "Common.h" whether it directly uses anything from the header or not, or else it will break. Invisible dependencies aren't any friendlier to the developer than they are to the user (latter of which doesn't matter in this case).

Comment: I don't disagree, and I am biased in favor of your position.  I'd go step further (and a different direction, I suppose) and comment on how much I despise macro identifiers and macro functions.

Answer (score 0):

The `*.inl` extension is *usually* used to indicate that the file is an inline-definition of something defined in a header. Effectively, the `*.inl` file is generally treated as an inline-equivalent to a `*.cpp` file.

In the same way that `*.cpp` files can use symbols `#include`d in the header for that `*.cpp` file, `*.inl` files usually have the same assumption.

In this specific example. it appears that `Functions.inl` is included [after a bunch of other headers are included](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/8f68bf07dfd134df3b90e83a63535d053bae9a8a/MiniEngine/Core/VectorMath.h#L60)

```cpp
#include "Math/Scalar.h"
#include "Math/Vector.h"
#include "Math/Quaternion.h"
#include "Math/Matrix3.h"
#include "Math/Transform.h"
#include "Math/Matrix4.h"
#include "Math/Functions.inl"
```

Which likely transitively pick up the `INLINE` macro